# How can i create a compass like current iphone

Tags: iphone

I want to create a compass app that function exactly the same as current iphone !  Can somebody point me direction ,please?  I am new at this !

Answer (score 2):

How to create an Compass in iOS:

Step 1: Create a project (e.g. CompassExample) and include frameworks

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

ViewContoller.h Steps:

Step 2: In .h file, create Location Manager Object

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager;
<CLLocationManagerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic,retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@synthesize locationManager;
IBOutlet UIImageView *compassImage;
```

Step 3: [Dowload this Compass Image](https://github.com/kiichi/CompassExample/blob/master/CompassExample/compass_needle.png)

ViewController.m Steps:

Step 4: In .m file’s viewDidLoad function, initialize the location manager.

```
    locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.headingFilter = 1;
    locationManager.delegate=self;
    [locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
```

Step 5: In .m file, implement delegate function.

First, you need to convert degree (e.g 360) to radian (e.g 3.14=2PI).
Second, multiply -1 in order to rotate opposite direction that you twist your phone.
Third, apply rotation with core animation function. In this example, I’m rotating from the current value to the new value. The duration is 0.5 second as you see below.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading{
    // Convert Degree to Radian and move the needle
    float oldRad =  -manager.heading.trueHeading * M_PI / 180.0f;
    float newRad =  -newHeading.trueHeading * M_PI / 180.0f;
    CABasicAnimation *theAnimation;
    theAnimation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
    theAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:oldRad];
    theAnimation.toValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:newRad];
    theAnimation.duration = 0.5f;
    [compassImage.layer addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"animateMyRotation"];
    compassImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(newRad);
    NSLog(@"%f (%f) => %f (%f)", manager.heading.trueHeading, oldRad, newHeading.trueHeading, newRad);
}
```

That’s it! Of course, you have to deploy the app on your device to check the direction.

Credit for this Code goes to kiichi, you can download the Project at [Github Link](https://github.com/kiichi/CompassExample)